# How to write RXjava 2 test for a behavior subject abstracted behind an interface

Tags: android, junit, rx-java, rx-java2

I have a behavior subject that will be DI. I then have different interfaces, that subscribe to that object. Below is a super simple one I am writing so that I can mostly restrict access to the subjects onNext() function. I am not able to figure out how to write a test for this in jUnit. This is RXjava2. I see a lot of blog posts that talk about tests Observers, testScheduler and so on, but none of them seem to block till a RX observable receives the next element.. My abstraction is not helping so I cant play with test observers and test observables, but is a requirement.

```
fun subscribe(subscribeThread: Scheduler, observeThread: Scheduler, next: Consumer<Location>, throwable: Consumer<Throwable>): Disposable {
    return publishSubject
            .subscribeOn(subscribeThread)
            .observeOn(observeThread)
            .subscribe(next, throwable)
}
```

I have my tests..

```
 private var consumerResult: Consumer<Val> = Consumer { count++ }

   @Test
    fun `dispose custom and receive updates`() {

    var disposable = myObserver.subscribe(testScheduler, testScheduler, consumerResult, consumerThrowable)
    assertNotNull(disposable)
    assertEquals(0, count)
    subject.onNext(mockVal)
    assertEquals(1, count) // FAILS
}
```

Which yes I expect it to fail as this is an async call. However I am not able to figure out how to write this so I can test my code.. Note this is the first step in a much larger complicated test

Comment: What's the value of `count` when it fails? Is it 0 or bigger?

Answer (score 0):

Without [`TestObserver`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/observers/TestObserver.html) I don't believe you'll be able to accomplish this. My recommendation would be to leverage the [`@VisibleForTesting`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/annotation/VisibleForTesting) annotation and write methods for passing an Observer to your Subject.

As an aside, I'm not sure I'm clear on how your approach succeeds in restricting access as you still allow for a `Consumer` to be passed into the subscription.